# Brwonian Process ITO Integral

Tags: brownian-motion

Briefly I am on a calculus course and right now we are learning Brownian Motion, its properties and proofs. And I have a question such as below in my study set that I cant find a solution. I would apreciate any help.

Show that,

$d(W(t)^n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}W(t)^{(n-2)}dt + nW(t)^{(n-1)}dW(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,t) = x^n$, for $n \geq 2$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = nx^{n-1},\quad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$

Let also $X_t = W_t$, and apply Ito's lemma to $f(X_t)$
$$df(X_t) = d(W_t^n)$$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Then it should be;   as nW^{n-1}d(Wt)  + dt   am I right?  of course sigma is 1 and mean is 0 here ?

Comment: With my notation, $dX_t = 0\cdot dt + 1 \cdot dW_t$, so yes, but be sure to apply thorougsly Ito's lemma: $df(X_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(X_t)dt +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(X_t)dX_t + \frac12  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(X_t)\sigma^2_tdt$

Comment: Thanks & sorry for the confusion derived from my notation.